# How to exclude node_modules directory

Tags: spring, maven

Below is the directory structure of my Spring MVC project.
Since the size of the node_modules, I want to exclude the directory during the maven build.

I have tried several methods, but none of them worked for me.

Below is the build part of pom.xml

```
<build>
<finalName>ROOT</finalName>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>node_modules</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </configuration>
    <version>3.1</version>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

[image]

Also I tried warSourceExcludes, but also it didn't work.

Please share any of your idea.

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issues, and the provided answer does not work either even when you fix the type he made as it's clearly **/src/main/webapp/node_modules not **/src/main/java/webapp. I'm having to put the package.json at the higher level and deal with the modules differently.

Comment: Did anyone get this problem solved?

Comment: @Jokus: Just move node folder outside the app and config webpack to put generated files in the right folder inside src/main/java/webapp ...

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/src/main/java/webapp/node_modules/*</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </configuration>
    <version>3.1</version>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Nope, it is not working. Even when we are doing same in maven-war-plugin that is also not working.